# Python: Doubles in a random generator

Tags: python, random, generator

I am try to create a generator that will look for n random integers in the range of 1 to m. The code below does exactly that however it will sometimes return a double of a number previously printed. Does anyone know how I can edit that? Another thing but it is more design-wise is, how can I order my print out so that the numbers are in order?

```
import random

def hwset(m,n):
    i=0
    for i in range(0,n):
        print random.randrange(1,m+1,1)
```

Comment: You mean you get numbers repeated? Are you trying to produce a *sample* instead perhaps?

Comment: Yes that is a better way to describe it. What is a sample?

Comment: A sample is a particular drawing from a population. 1 to m is the population, you are taking a n drawings from this, without replacement.

Comment: @UsernameUnknown: it is selection from a larger set, picked at random without repetition.

Comment: Note that your function is *not* a generator function; you have a regular function that prints values, instead. Do you really need a generator? Picking a sample from a larger set is not really suitable to a generator approach.

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to produce a sample of `n` numbers out of all integers between 1 and `m`, use the [`random.sample()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) with an `xrange()` object (use `range()` if you are on Python 3):

```
def hwset(m, n):
    return random.sample(xrange(1, m + 1), n)
```

If you wanted those numbers to be sorted, just sort the result:

```
sorted_hwset = sorted(hwset(m, n))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> def hwset(m, n):
...     return random.sample(xrange(1, m + 1), n)
... 
>>> hwset(100, 5)
[25, 58, 2, 29, 57]
>>> hwset(100, 5)
[84, 55, 80, 65, 47]
>>> sorted(hwset(100, 5))
[1, 25, 77, 81, 92]
>>> sorted(hwset(100, 5))
[34, 46, 59, 66, 76]
```

Comment: Perfect my function now workes but I cant get the sorting to work

Comment: @UsernameUnknown: define not working, here? You mean you have a sequence that is not ordered?

Comment: Yes, I do not have a sequence that is ordered

Comment: @UsernameUnknown: I've added a small demo; `sorted()` *returns* a new list in sorted order. You can also use `result = hwset(m, n)` then call `result.sort()` to sort the resulting list in-place.